# Setting a value to pointer causes program to crash

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int* n;
     *n = 20; // causes the crash
     printf("%d\n", *n);
     return 0;
}
```

but for some reason if i first set int* n = i then I can change the value with *n = 20
there a reason for this?

```
 int i = 19;
 int* n;
 *n = i;
 *n = 20;
```

edit: thank you everyone for helping i learned a lot from your answers.

Comment: It's *dereferencing an invalid pointer causes program to crash*.

Comment: You have a pointer pointing to nowhere and store a value to what it points to. Q: Where do you store the value?

Comment: Note that the second example is just as egregiously bad as the first example, and invokes undefined behaviour, just like the first — you're using an uninitialized pointer, and anything can happen when you do that.  There's no guarantee that the program will crash when you do things wrong, but it is a common response.  Another common response is it will seem to work, but what it does isn't what you intended.

Comment: A decent compiler should warn about the use of the uninitialized `n`.

Answer (score 4):

```
int* n;
 *n = i;
```

No, all you see (in both of your examples) is result of [undefined behavior](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c?qid=a1e4ecc1-8319-4915-80eb-64a3ef2b3d2d&v=&b=&from_search=1). Above you didn't initialize the pointer to point to a meaningful memory - by applying `*` operator you are dereferencing the pointer and telling it to write some value to the memory it *points to*, but since you didn't make it *point to* valid memory - you can't write through that pointer.

This would be fine

```
int x = 0;
int* n = &x; // Now your pointer points to valid memory
*n = 5; // Value of x will be 5 now
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a reason. When you declare :

```
int* n;
```

pointer `n` shows ***nowhere***. So when you try to set its value by

```
*n = 20;
```

the program crashes as you are trying to access the contents of a pointer showing nowhere.

---

On the other hand, when you declare

```
int i = 19;
int* n;
n = &i;
```

*you make the pointer* `n` ***show to some valid address***. So when afterwards you assign

```
*n = 20;
```

you actually access the contents of a *valid memory address*.

Comment: that should be `n = &i`

Comment: @Marievi: welcome, but remove the * from n on the second line too :)

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you can't set the value using that pointer is because its not pointing to a memory address yet, you need to use malloc and give it something to point to.

Hope this helps :D

E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *n;

    n = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *n = 20;

    printf("n = %d\n", *n);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```